# pymssql not updating database

Tags: python, sql-server, pymssql

I've got a script to merge some databases and I'm using python and pymssql to connect to the SQL Server databases.

The problem is that I run some update queries like (not worry for now with the SQL injection thing):

```
cursor.execute("UPDATE Servicos SET Saldo = Saldo + " + str(saldo) + " WHERE UtilizadorID=" + str(row_un['ID']) + " and ServicoID=1")
```

And my database doesn't get updated. I tried to pass the `autocommit=True` in the connect method and also the `conn.commit()` after the executed and both failed as my database didn't change after my updates (and I after I closed the connection).

I'm using Python27 and in a windows environment. Any ideas what's going on?

Thanks :)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to specify precisely what you mean when you say that your attempts "failed". Did you receive an error, and if so, what did it say?

Comment: I didn't receive any error. When the script ended I checked my database to validade the changes and nothing had changed. (Inside my script, before I close the connection I did some queries to check the changes and the database was changed). That's why I figure it may be something to do with a commit.

Comment: Please provide fuller code and not just one line snippet including connection method (obviously censor the credentials). Are you wrapping action in a `try/except` to catch exceptions? Also, it looks like you run this in a loop.